# Struggling to install broadcom 4311 on a HP 530 laptop running ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, hp, broadcom

I have ubuntu 12.10 on a HP530 laptop, I've tried everything on the ubuntu forums, but can't get the wireless to work. It has Broadcom 4311 wireless card built in. Don't know what else to try, please assist. I have the broadcom bcm4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01) card in my laptop. Alot of sites says to not to install proprietary broadcom driver as it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should make it work:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-sources
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: thank you, as soon as I do as above, I get this: DKMS: install completed.
ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules. Is something missing? or will it be ok?

Comment: That is an error because you do not have linux sources. I have updated my question, now pls run the commands in the order that I wrote them.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same errors and the linux-sources and install linux-hearders doesn't help. I get these:E: Unable to locate package linux-sources
and for headers I get:linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  calligra-l10n-engb cdparanoia k3b k3b-data k3b-i18n language-pack-kde-en
  libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libflac++6 libk3b6 libmpcdec6 module-assistant
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: under additional drivers I see that the broadcom driver/card is enabled. That fine?

Comment: I have the broadcom bcm4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01) card in my laptop

Comment: run this command 'uname -a' and tell me what it says.

Answer (score 0):

The Broadcom proprietary driver, provided by bcmw-kernel-source, is incorrect for 14e4:4311. Please do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot and enjoy your wireless.